# Regular expression language reference?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Is there a reference for the regular expression language included in C++11 (i.e. not the regex library)?

I know it's a slightly modified version of ECMAScript regexes, and I know that the Boost regex library is similar. However, it would be nice to have a definitive reference specifically for C++11.

Comment: "i.e. not the regex library" Um, what does *that* mean? The RegEx library is the *only* support for Regular Expressions in C++11.

Comment: Sorry, I was struggling a bit with explaining that. I don't want documentation for basic_regex, regex_match, regex_replace, regex_iterator and so on. What I'd like to find is documentation of the capabilities of the regular expression language that the regex library can process (at least the modified ECMAScript variant of it). So far "The C++ Standard Library Extensions" from the answer below seems like the best source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitive reference would be §28.13 of the C++11 standard (along with ECMA 262).

Although theoretically somewhat less definitive, [*The C++ Standard Library Extensions*](http://www.petebecker.com/tr1book/tr1book.html) describes what's in TR1, which I believe was used without modification in C++11. The author (Pete Becker) also happens to be the editor on the C++11 committee, so even though it's not entirely authoritative, I think it's safe to guess that its description of the standard is fairly accurate (though the linked page does have a short list of errata).

Comment: I'd like something like the Boost regex library documentation, but for C++11. The C++ standard and ECMA 262 aren't like that as far as I can see, I'm not after a formal regex grammar definition. I'll check out the book, thanks.